# Sed: What is wrong with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have written a `sed` regex (Mostly with the help of SO) to update the value in the json file which could be in the form of,

1 - `"XXXX" : "YYYY"`

or

2 - `"XXXX" : "YYYY",`

or

3 - `"XXXX" : YYYY`

or

4 -  `"XXXX" : YYYY,`

or

5 - `"XXXX" : "YYYY,ZZZZ"`

Here is my `sed` regex

`sed -r 's/("XXXX"\s*:\s*)(")?[^",]*(")?/\1\2YYYY\3/'` file

Above expression works for 1-4 format.

But for 5  it updates like below,

`"XXXX" : "YYYY,ZZZZ"` to `"XXXX" : "ZZZZ,ZZZZ"` (Expected : `"XXXX" : "ZZZZ"`)

What's wrong with my regex?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sed` regex, but my general goto resource for RE is http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm EDIT: Are the options (1-5) the items you are expecting to catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not worried about the value you are replacing will not a simpler pattern suffice

```
sed -r 's/("XXXX"\s*:\s*).*$/\1"YYYY",/' input
```

Or you can treat the quoted and unquoted ones separately

```
 sed -r 's/("XXXX"\s*:\s*)((")[^"]*"|[^,]*)/\1\3YYYY\3/' input
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I tried it but updated values missing starting quote,

`sed -r 's/("XXXX"\s*:\s*)((")[^"]*"|[^,]*)/\1\AAA\3/' sedtest

"XXXX" : AAA"

"XXXX" : AAA",

"XXXX" : AAA

"XXXX" : AAA,
"XXXX" : AAA"`

Comment: @indiws thanks. missed adding the `\3` reference in the beginning. updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `?` means 0 or 1.  You used `(")?` to capture an optional quote.  Instead in this case because the body part `[^",]*` can't match YYYY,ZZZZ the body and the trailing quote don't match at all (which is allowed:  zero body due to `*` and zero quote due to `?`) so your substitution only operates on the first part of the line `"XXXX" : "` and the rest just doesn't get substituted.

One idea is to replace the body `*` with `+` to require a body.  You might also want to bind the expression with `^` and `$` so you know you match the whole line to avoid confusion like this.

Answer (score 1):

This might be doing what you want:

```
sed -r 's/("XXXX"\s*:\s*)(")?[^",]*[^"]*/\1\2YYYY/' input
```

however, I don't know why do yu  expect `"XXXX" : "ZZZZ"` for the last one since there is no `ZZZZ` in your replace string.

Comment: I expect even if there are comma separated values as in `"XXXX" : "YYYY,ZZZZ"` it should be updated to single value `"XXXX" : "ZZZZ"`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But it doesnt retain comma at the end in the 4th case.